# how to build different variants of android through gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build-script

I already have

> 2 flavours (staging, production)
>
> 2 buildTypes (debug, release)

beyond that, I want to have different variants for, say, different vendors.
like a production-release build for samsung and htc. is it possible through build scripts?

PS: I don't want to use 3rd party plugin like [this](https://github.com/ihrthk/android-gradle-mulchannel-plugin)

Comment: You've already created 2 flavors, I don't understand why can't you just use the same procedure to create other flavors?

Comment: @kai bcz its like a 3rd level of variant. its same as say, prod-release build, just that some branding parameters will be different for different vendors. I agree its possible through buildTypes, but for each vendor i'ld need 2 entries, though manageable but slight messy.

Comment: I see what you mean now, but I don't think you really need a "staging-release" build? In that case you just need to define 3 build types (staging, production-debug, production-release), leaving flavors to be used exclusively for branding/customization purpose. That is what I did for one of my project and I can't complain about the setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use flavor dimensions.

```
android {
    flavorDimensions 'environment', 'vendor'

    productFlavors {
        staging {
            flavorDimension 'environment'
        }

        production {
            flavorDimension 'environment'
        }

        htc {
            flavorDimension 'vendor'
        }

        samsung {
            flavorDimension 'vendor'
        }
    }
}
```